# RESTEasy 3 broken with Spring 4.0

Tags: spring, resteasy

I am using Spring 4, Resteasy 3.0.6 and Tomcat 7

Tomcat startup fine but I get a 404 for all REST endpoints.

I think I am running into exactly is described here:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1012

I created that custom class and updated the web.xml
`<listener>
<listener-class>com.example.CustomContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>`

However now I get this exception and Tomcat fails to start

`SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
 Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].Stand
ardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletCo
ntainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitiali
zer(ContextConfig.java:1661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInit
ializers(ContextConfig.java:1569)`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The problem was that javax-servlet was a compile dependency so I had to change its scope to provided as that was causing a conflict with Tomcat (I'm using Maven)

Comment: do you have gist or the working code posted somewhere? I am trying to get Spring Boot to work with RESTEasy bt I have no idea how to get it to work. (No problem with Spring 3.x)

Comment: @jett look at the ticket that I linked, that has all the details https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1012

Comment: thank for pointing out. I actually posted on the Jira issue and thankfully the poster responded with a detailed example.